# C++ compiles & runs in Geany, not in Netbeans, Eclipse, Code::Blocks. Why?

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, geany

I'm learning C++ in a class. They have us using Geany on a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu. I miss the powers of an IDE, so I tried several: Netbeans, Eclipse and Code::Blocks.

The code I have for a homework compiles and runs with no problems in Geany on the VM. When I tried all the other IDEs, the compiler gives me an error. I tried Netbeans and Eclipse on Windows 7 and Ununtu in the same VM. In searching for an answer, [this help topic](http://tnbforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=118&t=23191) says that Geany is doing a lot behind the scenes for me. So I've tried playing with removing the various `#include` statements I have for the headers and source codes, and <s>solved the problem</s> (Just kidding!) and can't figure out what's really happening.

ArrayBagTester2.cxx: (this is what I compile/run in Geany)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ArrayBag.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        // a bunch of stuff
    }
```

ArrayBag.h: (provided by the professor with no changes made/needed)

```
#ifndef _ARRAY_BAG
#define _ARRAY_BAG

#include "BagInterface.h"
template<class ItemType>
class ArrayBag : public BagInterface<ItemType>
{
    private:
        static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 4;
        ItemType* itemArray; //array must be dynamic; so pointers are very yes
        int numberOfItems;
        int myCapacity; //added variable to track capacity

    public:
        ArrayBag(int capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY); // new constructor
        ArrayBag(const ArrayBag& anotherBag); // copy constructor
        ~ArrayBag(); //destructor
        int getCurrentSize() const;
        int getCapacity() const;
        void resize(int newCapacity); // resize
        bool isEmpty() const;
        bool isFull() const;
        bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
        bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
        void clear();
        bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
        int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
        vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
        ArrayBag& operator=(const ArrayBag& anotherBag);
};

#include "ArrayBag.cxx"
#endif
```

BagInterface.h (Provided by text book author, note copyright. I have crippled to maintain their copyright.)

```
//  Created by Frank M. Carrano and Tim Henry.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 __Pearson Education__. All rights reserved.

/** Listing 1-1.
    @file BagInterface.h */
#ifndef _BAG_INTERFACE
#define _BAG_INTERFACE

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class BagInterface
{
public:
   virtual .... stuff here, all virtual functions ...
};
#endif
```

ArrayBag.cxx: The meat and potatoes and what we're supposed to (solely) edit, errors start at line 9:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>

#include "ArrayBag.h"

// Constructor; creates and initializes an empty Bag of "capacity" size
template <class ItemType>
********************//LINE 9:**************************
ArrayBag<ItemType>::ArrayBag(int capacity)
{
    myCapacity = capacity;
    itemArray = new ItemType[myCapacity];
    numberOfItems = 0;
}

// Copy constructor; creates and initializes Bag from another Bag
template <class ItemType>
ArrayBag<ItemType>::ArrayBag(const ArrayBag& anotherBag)
{
    numberOfItems = anotherBag.getCurrentSize();
    myCapacity = anotherBag.getCapacity();
    itemArray = new ItemType[myCapacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; ++i)
        itemArray[i] = anotherBag.itemArray[i];
}

//destructor
template <class ItemType>
ArrayBag<ItemType>::~ArrayBag()
{
    delete [] itemArray;
}

// Assignment operator
template <class ItemType>
ArrayBag<ItemType>& ArrayBag<ItemType>::operator=(const ArrayBag<ItemType>& anotherBag)
{
    // see if we're trying to assign to ourself, stupid user
    if (&anotherBag == this)
        return *this;
    clear();
    //ArrayBag<ItemType>::~ArrayBag();
    delete [] itemArray;
    //ArrayBag<ItemType>::ArrayBag(anotherBag);
    numberOfItems = anotherBag.getCurrentSize();
    myCapacity = anotherBag.getCapacity();
    itemArray = new ItemType[myCapacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; ++i)
        itemArray[i] = anotherBag.itemArray[i];

    return *this;
}

// Return the number of Items being stored in the Bag
template <class ItemType>
int ArrayBag<ItemType>::getCurrentSize() const
{
    return numberOfItems;
}

// Return the capacity of the bag (the maximum Items it can store)
template <class ItemType>
int ArrayBag<ItemType>::getCapacity( ) const
{
    return myCapacity;
}

//Resizes the bag's capacity to newCapacity
//if the new size is larger, copy all bag contents
// we don't downsize a bag in HW2
template <class ItemType>
void ArrayBag<ItemType>::resize(int newCapacity)
{
    ItemType* oldArray = itemArray;
    itemArray = new ItemType[newCapacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < myCapacity; ++i)
        itemArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    delete [] oldArray;
}

// Report whether the Bag is empty
// Return true if the Bag is empty (storing no Items);
// Return false if Items exist in the Bag
template <class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return (numberOfItems == 0);
}

// Report whether the Bag is full
// Return true if the Bag is filled to capacity
// Return false if there is still room
template <class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::isFull() const
{
    //This bag is resizeable, so it's never full
    return false;
}

// Give the Bag a new Item to store
// If Bag is full, double capacity and add newItem
// Else, Bag must add this Item to its Item array and update its numberOfItems
// If Bag is full after this, return true; else return false
template <class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newItem)
{
    if (numberOfItems == myCapacity)
    {
        resize(myCapacity * 2);
        myCapacity = myCapacity * 2;
    }

    itemArray[numberOfItems++] = newItem;

    //This bag is resizeable, so it's never full
    return false;
}

// Make the Bag act like an empty Bag again
template <class ItemType>
void ArrayBag<ItemType>::clear()
{
    numberOfItems = 0;
}

// Remove an Item from the bag
// If Item is not there, nothing changes and we return false
// Else, we fill in its spot in that Item array and count number of Items down
template <class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& anItem)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; ++i)
    {
        if (itemArray[i] == anItem)
        {
            itemArray[i] = itemArray[--numberOfItems];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Check if an Item is in the Bag
// Return true if it is in the Bag, and false if not
template <class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anItem) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; ++i)
        if (itemArray[i] == anItem) return true;
    return false;
}

// Check how many times an Item is in the Bag
// return 0 if it's not there; otherwise,
// return the number of times it occurs
template <class ItemType>
int ArrayBag<ItemType>::getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anItem) const
{
    int frequency = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; ++i)
        if (anItem == itemArray[i]) ++frequency;

    return frequency;
}

// Make an output vector of Items from the bag (for checking)
template <class ItemType>
vector<ItemType> ArrayBag<ItemType>::toVector() const
{
    vector<ItemType> bagContents;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; ++i)
        bagContents.push_back(itemArray[i]);

    return bagContents;
}
```

Here is the error generated for each method in the ArrayBag.cxx:

> C:\Users...\HW2\ArrayBag.cxx|9|error: redefinition of
>   'ArrayBag::ArrayBag(int)'|
>   C:\Users...\HW2\ArrayBag.cxx|9|error:
>   'ArrayBag::ArrayBag(int)' previously declared here
>
> ... Truncated for clarity ...

I would like to understand:

1. **Why does Geany work when the others do not?** What really is that make makefile magic?
2. Is there an (easy) *fix* to Netbeans (not that Netbeans is causing the problem) on Windows to fix this? (I seem to prefer Netbeans, no other reason.) or:
3. What is a more *traditional* or *standard* way of including these relationships and files?

Comment: How do you compile those files ?

Comment: Instead of this monstrousity of code, why not a simple "Hello World" program to test these various IDE's?

Comment: @hivert In Geany, I click the Bookshelf icon, and then the gears icon. The command window has `g++ -Wall -g -o "%e" "%f"` is the Build command in Geany.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hello World's do compile/run fine on all. This monstrosity of code is the problem.

Comment: It could be that some compilers attempt to compile `ArrayBag.cxx`, which is not meant to be compiled. But I wouldn't trust code with reserved names and `using namespace std` in header files.

Comment: MECU: I don't need the compile command which works but the one which doesn't ;-)

Comment: #include <iostream>
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World";
}

Right there, you are testing the include paths, whether you're using a compliant compiler underneath the hood, etc.  No need for anything more than this to test if your IDE is acting right.

Comment: @hivert `mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c C:\Users\...\HW2\ArrayBag.cxx -o obj\Debug\ArrayBag.o`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hello World's compile and run fine. The IDE is therefore not the problem, this code and something "specialized" with Geany are the problem.

Comment: The g++ compiler works the same in all enviroments.  IDE's don't do anything except spawn g++ with the appropriate command-line arguments.  If your IDE didn't set the #include paths correctly, then again, a simple Hello World program and not much more than that can isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `ArrayBag.cxx` is included (which is very strange way of doing it but whatever) and is not meant to be compiled. Just compile `ArrayBagTester2.cxx` and it should be ok.

By the way: I agree with the previous comment that this thing is a monstrosity...

Comment: I found an option in Code::Blocks to tell it that the ArrayBag.cxx file should not be compiled. It didn't compile the .h files (automatically set that). It works fine now.

Comment: Do you have an answer on how to better include or a more standard way to include these? I'm just learning what the class teaches.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be compiling ArrayBag.cxx as a separate compilation unit.  See here:

[Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Template implementation files are *not* separate compilation units, but your command-line suggests that it was compiled as one.